# Prohibit IE Compatibility View for an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have various ASP.NET MVC 5 Applications that run fine on current IE and all other major browsers. The problem is that a lot of people have added the domain where the webapps run to the compatibility view sites, because of our Sharepoint. Without the compatibility view Sharepoint calendars do not work properly. Because of this setting all my pages also get compat view applied and that destroys layout quite a bit.

Basically the URLs are:
Sharepoint: sp.contoso.com
Webapps: web.contoso.com/app1

and if you add sp.contoso.com to compat view in IE, IE enables compat view for the full domain contoso.com.

I am aware that there are propably registry settings that could finetune the compat behavior, but that is no solution for our full company.

**Is there a way to prohibit compatibility view for my ASP.NET page from a developers or admins perspective?**

Answer (score 1):

Configure IIS to add the headers which control compatibility view. That way you can set compatibility view on the SharePoint site, and turn it off in other sites.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx